# Converting Tree-like table headers into an indented structure

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sorry for the terrible title, I don't know how to properly describe this.

I have a set of table headers that are hierarchical, and I need to transform them from a multi-column tree structure, to a single column indented structure.

The Tree like structure looks like this (Sorry it's photos, I can't render it in MD):

[image: Tree Structure]

And the version I would like to render looks like this:

[image: List Structure]

In the first photo, the yellow cells are rollup cells. They don't actually have any information, they just act as placeholders for alignment.

The data structure for the first table headers looks like essentially like this:

```json
{
    "headers": [
        [
            {
                "label": "A",
                "span": "9"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "label": "B",
                "span": "9"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "label": "C",
                "span": "1"
            },
            {
                "label": "D",
                "span": "4"
            },
            {
                "label": "E",
                "span": "1"
            },
            {
                "label": "F",
                "span": "3"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "rollup": true,
                "span": "1"
            },
            {
                "label": "G",
                "span": "2"
            },
            {
                "label": "H",
                "span": "2"
            },
            {
                "rollup": true,
                "span": "1"
            },
            {
                "label": "I",
                "span": "1"
            },
            {
                "label": "J",
                "span": "1"
            },
            {
                "label": "K",
                "span": "1"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "rollup": true,
                "span": "1"
            },
            {
                "label": "L",
                "span": "1"
            },
            {
                "label": "M",
                "span": "1"
            },
            {
                "label": "N",
                "span": "1"
            },
            {
                "label": "O",
                "span": "1"
            },
            {
                "rollup": true,
                "span": "1"
            },
            {
                "rollup": true,
                "span": "1"
            },
            {
                "rollup": true,
                "span": "1"
            },
            {
                "rollup": true,
                "span": "1"
            },
        ],
    ]
}
```

And the data for the actual values in the table looks like this (it's possible to have many columns, this the nested arrays, furthermore it's possible to have empty values in which case there will be a flag that indicated it's an empty cell like `"empty":true`):

```json
const rows = {
    "data": [
        [
            {
                "value": 100
                "empty": false // Could be used to indicate a cell is empty
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "value": 200
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "value": 300
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "value": 400
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "value": 500
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "value": 600
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "value": 700
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "value": 800
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "value": 900
            }
        ],
    ]
}
```

I need to render the second header style, using the data above. This doesn't feel like it should be a very difficult problem, however I can't seem to solve it.

edit:

To render the data in the first table, we convert the initial data structure essentially into a 9x5 matrix, where the arrays are padded with `null` accordingly.

```json
const yHeaders = {
    "headers": [
        [
            {
                "label": "A",
                "span": "9",
            },
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
        ],
        [
            {
                "label": "B",
                "span": "9"
            },
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
        ],
        [
            {
                "label": "C",
                "span": "1",
            },
            {
                "label": "D",
                "span": "4",
            },
            null,
            null,
            null,
            {
                "label": "E",
                "span": "1",
            },
            {
                "label": "F",
                "span": "3",
            },
            null,
            null,
        ],
        [
            {
                "rollup": true,
                "span": "1",
            },
            {
                "label": "G",
                "span": "2",
            },
            null,
            {
                "label": "H",
                "span": "2",
            },
            null,
            {
                "rollup": true,
                "span": "1",
            },
            {
                "label": "I",
                "span": "1",
            },
            {
                "label": "J",
                "span": "1",
            },
            {
                "label": "K",
                "span": "1",
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "rollup": true,
                "span": "1",
            },
            {
                "label": "L",
                "span": "1",
            },
            {
                "label": "M",
                "span": "1",
            },
            {
                "label": "N",
                "span": "1",
            },
            {
                "label": "O",
                "span": "1",
            },
            {
                "rollup": true,
                "span": "1",
            },
            {
                "rollup": true,
                "span": "1",
            },
            {
                "rollup": true,
                "span": "1",
            },
            {
                "rollup": true,
                "span": "1",
            },
        ],
    ]
}
```

To render the current table, we use something like this:

```js
const renderBodyRow = (row: any, key: number, rows: any) => {
  return (
    <tr key={key}>
      {yHeaders.headers.map((yHeaderColumn: any[], rowColumnHeaderKey: number) => {
        // For many of these, yHeaderColumn[key] will be null, in which case the previous
        // row will simply span into the new one
        return (
          yHeaderColumn.length > key &&
          yHeaderColumn[key] && (
            <th
              key={rowColumnHeaderKey}
              rowSpan={+get(yHeaderColumn[key], "span", 1)}
            >
              {get(yHeaderColumn[key], "label")}
            </th>
          )
        );
      })}
      {row.map((cell: any, cellIndex: number) => {
        return <td key={cellIndex}>{get(cell, "value", "")}</td>;
      })}
    </tr>
  );
};


return (
        <table id={tableId}>
          <thead>...</thead>
          <tbody >
            {rows.data.map(renderBodyRow)}
          </tbody>
        </table>
)
```

Comment: where is the letter col going to? what have you tried?

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: Creating a table with a "header" column like the figure is easily done with margins. Yet the question needs more detail to suggest a solution.  Please show the code you use to convert the data to an html table.

Comment: OK, I added some more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a virtual target by using span and the intermediate indices to get a tree structure and render a flat array with indented label and value, denoted here with `data[0]`, which should be replaced by the real values.

```js
const
    headers = [[{ label: "A", span: "9" }], [{ label: "B", span: "9" }], [{ label: "C", span: "1" }, { label: "D", span: "4" }, { label: "E", span: "1" }, { label: "F", span: "3" }], [{ rollup: true, span: "1" }, { label: "G", span: "2" }, { label: "H", span: "2" }, { rollup: true, span: "1" }, { label: "I", span: "1" }, { label: "J", span: "1" }, { label: "K", span: "1" }], [{ rollup: true, span: "1" }, { label: "L", span: "1" }, { label: "M", span: "1" }, { label: "N", span: "1" }, { label: "O", span: "1" }, { rollup: true, span: "1" }, { rollup: true, span: "1" }, { rollup: true, span: "1" }, { rollup: true, span: "1" }]],
    iter = (array, index = { i: 0 }) => array.flatMap(({ label, children }) => [
        [label, children.length ? '' : `data[${index.i++}]`],
        ...iter(children, index)
    ]),
    temp = [];

headers.reduce((r, a, i) => {
    const parents = {};
    let pos = 0;
    a.forEach(({ label, span, rollup }) => {
        span *= 1;
        label = '  '.repeat(i) + label;
        if (!rollup) {
            r[pos].push({ label, children: parents[pos] = [] });
            for (let i = 1; i < span; i++) parents[pos + i] = parents[pos];
        }
        pos += span;
    });
    return parents;
}, { 0: temp });
    

console.log(iter(temp));
console.log(temp);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked wonderfully. I'm a little bit lost in the `reduce` section though, specifically the children. What exactly does `children: parents[pos] = []` do? Is this just to save a line of code instead of doing the assignment on the previous line?

Comment: it takes the reference to the nested span elements. it is not only shorter, but it avaoids to pull out the inserted object to gth the nested array for children.